# Configurable Products - Change Dropdown based on first dropdown selection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to set up a product that is very similar to a configurable product but where the options can change depending on the attribute that has been selected. For instance, if I had the following attributes `Size` and `Colour`. Lets say I had `small`, `medium`, `large` for the `size` attribute. On my product, red is only available in the `medium` size but green and blue are available in all sizes. I would need the `colour` drop down box to change based on the selection of the `size` drop down.

Is this possible?

Note: I know this isn't strictly a programming question but I have seen a lot of other "setup" questions about magento on SO that haven't been closed so assume this appropriate.

Comment: Why don't you just use configurable products? this is what they are meant for. Simple only add stock for the combinations you want and Magento will take care of the dropdowns for you :)

Comment: If you do this in code you will need to change the code if say in the future red is available in Large..

Comment: @Andrew - I want to use configurable products but from what I can see they only allow a static list of options, nothing like "If this option is selected, only show these options in the next drop down". If you can confirm this is possible, I will keep digging to try and set it up.

Comment: @Andrew - I think I just caught on to what you are saying and I may be over complicating it. I am going to set up the products now assuming that if an option doesn't have an item then it won't show. Will report back.

Comment: Configurable products will do what you want.
if you select say Size first, and there's no "Red" colour options for that size then it will not appear in the second dropdown. It's dynamically generated depending on what variations you have

Comment: @Andrew - You are correct, I assumed it wasn't as clever as it is. If you convert your comments into an answer I will accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Configurable prodcuts to do this for you. Configurable products will only allow the user to select variations you have setup in the store.

for example:

If you have a configurable prodcut with Size and Colour Attributes, and add variations as follows:

Size: S, M, L
Colour: Red, Blue

You then only add (and enable/make in stock) Variations (simple child products) with combinations where Red is available in S,M only, and Blue is abailable in size L.

When a user tries to buy the product they will be asked to select a size, if they then select Size: S then the Colour dropdown will dynamically change to only allow the user to select Red as an option.